# Any specific name for EFI Boot Loader?

Tags: uefi, gpt

Isn't there any specific name for EFI Boot Loader?

As in **Windows** **BIOS MBR**, **NTLDR** is Boot Loader and For **Linux MBR** it is **GRUB** and for LINUX EFI it is GRUB 2

Where does the process begins in UEFI mode? Is it ESP first that will carry out EFI Boot Loader and then further? Any role for GPT come in between?

Comment: This is rather a lot of questions in one.  You could read rodsbooks [Managing EFI Boot Loaders for Linux:
Basic Principles](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) for an overview of UEFI boot process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific name for EFI Boot Loader, because such a bootloader does not
really exist.

Bootstrapping on EFI involves a boot manager that is **built in to the firmware**.
EFI systems do not rely upon bootstrap programs stored in boot records
(VBRs or MBRs) at all. The firmware knows how to read a partition table and
understands the FAT filesystem format, which the IBM PC compatible firmware cannot do
and needs to load a program for that.

A designated partition, that is formatted with the FAT filesystem format and
identified with a specific well-known partition type, is known as the
EFI System Partition, which the firmware knows how to find.

The EFI System Partition is a true system volume that is identified by its
type code in the partition table, with no need for guessing like in the
Microsoft's System Reserved Partition.
It contains specific boot loader programs, which are EFI executable programs
that are loaded and run by the EFI boot manager.

EFI executable programs are standalone programs, that use only machine firmware
services and that do not require an underlying operating system in order to run.
They can be either operating system boot loaders or "pre-boot" maintenance/diagnosis
programs.
By convention, all of the boot loaders for all the operating systems are stored
in the EFI system partition  in a vendor-specific subdirectory of the `\EFI\`
directory.

For the 64-bit versions of Windows NT 5.x, the EFI boot loader is
`\EFI\Microsoft\WINNT50\IA64LDR.EFI`, or sometimes
`\EFI\Microsoft\WINNT50C\IA64LDR.EFI`.
It comprises NTLDR, the Windows NT boot loader that loads and executes the
Windows NT kernel from files in the Windows boot volume.

For Windows NT 6, the EFI boot loader is `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\Bootmgfw.efi`,
which is the Microsoft Boot Manager, which is a second boot manager which
may again present a second menu of boot options, listing more boot loader programs
to invoke and options to pass to them.

For the 64-bit versions of Linux, the EFI boot loader is either
`\EFI\RedHat\elilo.efi` or `\EFI\SuSE\elilo.efi`, which is a modified version of
LILO, the Linux boot loader that loads and executes the Linux kernel from files
in the system volume.

ELILO, like the Microsoft Boot Manager, contains a second level of boot options, held in a separate `elilo.conf` configuration file, rather than integrating support for such multiple boot options into the EFI boot loader and EFI variables.

For Apple, the firmware ignores most of the EFI specification on its Intel
Macintoshes. The EFI System Partition is empty and unused, and the EFI boot manager is obscured by an Apple boot loader that is executed before it.

For more information see:

- [Wikipedia EFI system partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition)
- [The EFI boot process](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/efi-boot-process.html)
- [UEFI boot: how does that actually work, then?](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't there any specific name for EFI Boot Loader?

There are *many* EFI boot loaders, just as there are many BIOS boot loaders. But their name is often exactly the same.

In Windows Vista and later:

- The boot manager (which shows the boot menu) is called the "Windows Boot Manager". Its file names differ between BIOS (`BOOTMGR`) and UEFI (`Bootmgfw.efi`), but it's called the Windows Boot Manager in both cases.
- The boot loader (which is started from the boot menu, and actually lauches Windows) is called the "Windows Boot Loader" or WINLOAD.EXE. Both modes eventually reach the same boot loader.

In Windows XP (which didn't support UEFI, but did support Itanium EFI):

- The BIOS bootloader/bootmanager was called "NTLDR".
- The EFI bootloader was stored in a file "IA64LDR.EFI".

On Linux, there are multiple boot managers and boot loaders available:

- GRUB 2.x supports both BIOS and UEFI systems, and it's called "GRUB 2" in both cases.
- Syslinux also supports both modes. The UEFI version of Syslinux is still called "Syslinux".
- There are some boot managers/loaders which are BIOS-only (e.g. LILO, GRUB 0.x), and some which are UEFI-only (e.g. systemd-boot, rEFInd, eLILO, efilinux).

> Where does the process begins in UEFI mode? Is it ESP first that will carry out EFI Boot Loader and then further? Any role for GPT come in between?

The "MBR" (Master Boot Record) held two things at once: BIOS boot code in the first 440 bytes, and the partition table in the remaining 72 bytes.

In contrast, the boot code isn't held in the GPT directly – GPT is *only* the partition table. Instead, EFI systems have a designated system partition (the ESP) where boot code is stored as regular files.

So neither the GPT nor ESP are capable of actually starting anything on their own. Instead, the EFI firmware directly starts *specific files* from the ESP.